# What is this data encoding?

Tags: json, encoding

I have an arduino project to make analog network bandwidth monitor.  I plan to get my data from a router running tomato firmware.  The router reports bandwidth in an HTTP responce where the payload contains:

```
netdev={ 'eth0':{rx:0xc8160edf,tx:0x611a4b81},'eth1':{rx:0x4f0b22e,tx:0x3903cd66},
'vlan1':{rx:0x96cb54a9,tx:0xb1aa0386},'vlan2':{rx:0xa55eec42,tx:0xaf7047fb},
'br0':{rx:0x8189e6d1,tx:0xb620299b},'imq3':{rx:0x0,tx:0x2912c02e},
'imq4':{rx:0xd15f62f,tx:0x0}};
```

a. Does anyone recognize this encoding?  Looks like json but wrapping the value names in single quote (') is not valid json.  A custom variant on json or something else?

b. If recognized, does anyone know of a c# library for decoding?

Comment: it is looking as `hex` code in `JSON` format -- `hex` as `hexadecimal`

Answer (score 0):

Just Hex encoding, 4 bit hex value maybe an int

you can pasrse it by yourself